# How to find polkadot js API implementation in rust susbtrate

Tags: polkadot-js, substrateinterface

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#accountaccountid32-framesystemaccountinfo

```
account(AccountId32): FrameSystemAccountInfo
interface: api.query.system.account
summary: The full account information for a particular account ID.
```

I want to find the substrate implementation in rust for the above polkadot js API interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if this is a Substrate pallet.

`'Substrate' repository -> 'frame' folder -> '<PALLET_NAME>'(here is system) -> <STORAGE_NAME>(here is account)`

e.g. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/29466db4b711730f5fa95f3fe1f289871b2c7c5c/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L529-L538

Comment: thank you so much